# Why is the U2F secret key on yubikeys is not programmable, and how to get a universal backup token?

Tags: backup, yubikey, u2f

I'm trying to figure the best strategy for having a backup U2F token. Ideally, I want to have two identical tokens; obviously I'll have the primary one easily accessible (say, on my keyring), but the second one I'd place somewhere not easily accessible (extreme cases are: bricked up into the wall, or buried somewhere in the forest). So whenever I register on a new service supporting U2F, I just use my primary token, and I know that the second one is also automatically supported. I consider this strategy a good tradeoff for being secure and still have a reliable backup option.

But apparently, with yubikeys, the only viable option is to have two distinct tokens and register *both of them manually* on every service I use them for. However, this is less than ideal because I'd have to keep both of them easily accessible: it's okay if I have to unbrick the backup token in a bad event of losing the primary one, but doing that for every new service is not viable.

Actually, I was surprised to find out that even though yubikeys do support programming of OTP key material (and they even have two slots, it's really nice), they do *not* support programming of the secret key used for U2F.

Is there any particular reason that U2F secret key on yubikeys is not programmable, even though secret data for other modes (e.g. OTP) is programmable?

Comment: your second question was off-topic for this site

Comment: Schroeder is right, the question of yubikeys not being programmable is off-topic, but if I had to speculate, it would be A) to prevent users from locking themselves out by overwriting their secret key and B) to prevent attackers from overwriting the original secret key with a known value before you receive it.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Actually that's the part that's on-topic :P The off-topic part was a product recommendation request.

Comment: I am wondering why so many people want to have a clone of their security device. Having a clone does neither increase security nor usability. I recently LOST my yubikey! If I had a clone, there would be no use in having a clone. The yubikey I LOST is COMPROMIZED, so I have to revoke or delete this device from the backend systems or services. At the same moment the clone would be compromized. And if I revoke the original key, the clone would be revoked, too and rendered useless.

Comment: @cornelinux It's all about tradeoffs. In theory, yes, the lost yubikey could be taken advantage of by someone. But, considering that, I still believe that at least personally for me, it's negligeably unlikely that anyone on earth would actually be able to make use of it (in a short period of time they have until I get a new token, login to my accounts using the backup, add a new one and revoke the old one). An U2F token is just one factor; I use keepassx to keep my passwords very strong, so they would also have to get access to that. Not saying it's impossible, but, again, negligeably unlikely

Comment: And I still consider having a very well hidden clone much more secure than having just a distinct token, which should be kept easily accessible (likely somewhere in my home) all the time, on a permanent basis. After all, an apartment could get robbed, in which case it's possible to lose both tokens, and it would be just unacceptably bad. All other recovery options (having authenticator app or recovery codes) suck even more.

Comment: @DmitryFrank I like the concept, if you use the backup to actually enroll a new token! ;-) I think we are on the same page here.

Comment: Note: many services do not enable one to register multiple tokens.  This unfortunate situation is part of the justification for wanting to have a clone backup.

Answer (score 2):

So while reading the [U2F overview](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.2-ps-20170411/fido-u2f-overview-v1.2-ps-20170411.pdf) I realized that what I want is impossible with the way U2F is designed, because device has a counter which is incremented on every authentication (see section 8.1 of the overview linked above)

So it's not about yubikey in particular, it's about the whole U2F. That's sad to me, I really liked the idea of having a clone which is hard to access even for me. Not being able to use that strategy means that we have to come up with other recovery methods, which will be different for every service (e.g. not every service supports adding multiple U2F tokens), and overall it's anyway less secure than two devices programmed with the same secrets.

Alas.

**UPD**: actually, I've got an idea. There is an open-source project [u2f-zero](https://github.com/conorpp/u2f-zero). So the plan is: get two devices, program them with the same secrets, BUT the backup device should be programmed with a small modification: instead of returning a plain counter from the cryptochip (u2f-zero uses ATECC508A), return something like `counter+500000`. I'm unlikely to exceed 500000 authentications during the whole life, and it's still a small fraction of the whole counter range anyway (which is 32-bit).

So, if I'm unlucky enough to lose my primary token, I go to the forest, dig out the backup token, and it should work for all of my services right away. There is even one nice side effect: after I use the backup token first time, the primary one will be immediately invalidated because its counter is lower.

**UPD2**: I wrote a detailed article about it: [Reliable, Secure and Universal Backup for U2F Token](https://dmitryfrank.com/articles/backup_u2f_token)

Comment: I kind of like downloadable recovery codes for this, as GitHub, Google, and a number of other providers use. You can print them out and keep them locked up, and it’s way less expensive as a backup solution.

Comment: Recovery codes have the same problem that I need to generate them for every service separately, so I have to keep them somewhere accessible (likely in my apartment). Burying them in the forest is not an option. As to the cost, well, $20 for a convenient universal backup is not much.

Comment: Maybe it’s nuance, but I disagree with it being the same problem as the flow is one way. You don’t need to dig out all your other recovery codes to sign up for a new service. You can download and print them off, storing them in your safe place at your convenience. Whereas signing up with a service and using your backup key requires you to retrieve the key.

Comment: That's true that I don't need to dig out existing keys to generate new ones, but I don't want to spread those codes around. I'd like to keep them in a single and quite safe place.

Comment: Actually, I think I've got an idea how to implement the desired strategy. I updated my answer, if you're interested.

Comment: The counter may not actually be an issue. If the counter is lower than the server's stored value, it indicates that a clone has been used or that (however unlikely) it has rolled over. But this means that the token with the lower counter is probably the legitimate one, and the server should definitely _warn_ the user about it, but what to do besides that is up to the application. There is an extensive discussion about it [here](https://github.com/Yubico/php-u2flib-server/issues/5). It would take some testing to see what most sites actually do in practice.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I wrote a detailed article about it: [Reliable, Secure and Universal Backup for U2F Token](https://dmitryfrank.com/articles/backup_u2f_token). And yeah @AndrolGenhald , I verified that at least Google and Github do respect the counter. Which is awesome (see details in the article).

Comment: Is there a reason not to use half of the counter's max value (2,147,483,648) instead of 500,000?

Comment: @EzekielElin actually the 500,000 was an oversight; there is an issue with the counter boost which can be easily addressed by using the boost value larger than the hardware counter's range. See details in the section [Caveat with the counter](https://dmitryfrank.com/articles/backup_u2f_token#caveat_with_the_counter). And yeah, using the value like 2,000,000,000 does solve an issue and is a better idea overall.

Comment: @nbering It is good to note that downloadable recovery codes are far inferior to U2F as the secrets themselves are sent over the Internet to your browser, then touch whatever is there (browser cache, clipboard, wherever you store them, etc).  With U2F, the user's secret _never leaves the device_ and even if the website / server is compromised, they don't have the user's secret.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into how devices like the Trezor implement U2F?  The device backs up all keys using a 12 or 24 word seed phrase, so they are easy to clone without keys ever touching a computer.  The [U2F counter is also restored](https://wiki.trezor.io/U2F#Restoring_U2F_Counter_on_Trezor) when recovering using the seed phrase. Apparently they [use the unix timestamp as the counter](https://www.reddit.com/r/TREZOR/comments/btcwb3/u2f_counter_restoration_after_recovery/eowb4df/) when restoring ensuring that it is always larger.  Of course this means you can only have 1 device working at a time, but if the first is lost / damaged, the second will have the correct counter after being restored.